# bcc emails are not delivered - Drupal 9 SMTP

Tags: email, drupal, smtp, drupal-8, smtp-auth

Below is my code to send out email using `plugin.manager.mail` in Drupal.

```
$params['context']['subject'] = t('[@site] A new event has been created');
$params['context']['message'] = $mode_info . '' .
                                'Hello User !' . '<br />' .
                                '<p class="notif-email">'.'A new event has been added to the PREP website. Below are the details of the new event: '. '<br />' .
                                'Event details: '.$event_details;
$s_recipients = implode(', ', $event_recipients);
$to = 'test@test.com';
$params['headers']['bcc'] = $s_recipients;
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('system', 'mail', $to, $langcode, $params);
```

I am not using hook_mail hook. rather, I call a custom method within node_presave hook to send out the email:

```
function mymodule_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if($entity->bundle() == 'events') {
    notify_new_events($entity, 'created'); //email piece is detailed within this method
  }
}
```

**Problem:**  Email is not sent out for bcc recipients. doing dd($params) shows params array with bcc addresses correctly. Any help on how this can be fixed pls?!

I am using SMTP authentication module to send out the emails.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and turns out a user had an invalid email on DB, like you have "test@test.com".

Try to use real emails to validate if it is because of that or not.

I am not seeing any error on your php code.